# View Info of a user when "Title" is pressed or tapped in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Been trying to make it happen, but so far i am lost.

This is my Model:

```
class Dbtusers {
  String iD;
  String loginName;
  String emailAdd;
  String password;
  String createdDateTime;
  String createdBy;
  String updatedBy;
  String iDUserType;
  String iDCompany;
  String iDRetailer;
  String isFullyReg;
  String loginStatus;
  String lastLogin;
  String fullName;
  String token;
  String isNewlyReg;
  String isActive;
  String isFirstTimeLogin;
  String contactNumber;
```

This is my List:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Dbtusers>>(
      future: dbgetdbusers(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData)
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        return ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Card(
              child: new Column(
                children: snapshot.data
                    .map((data) => ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            data.fullName,
                          ),
                        ))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

so far my list can only show "Full name". what i am trying to do is, when i tap or press the "Full Name" all of the other info like id loginname etc. will be shown in a card. Thanks!

Comment: You mean something like this? https://pub.dev/packages/expandable Maybe add an image to make it more clear what it is you want it to look like.

Comment: hmmm, i was thinking of using the "card" widget, but i can use this one. Thank you so much!!